# How to fix warning MSB3825 for a localizable WinForm containing a ListView with a Group?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-8.0

If you have a .NET 8 WinForms project with a localizable form that contains a `ListView` with a `Group`, you get a `MSB3825` warning about using `BinaryFormatter`, which is deprecated.

`BinaryFormatter` will be removed altogether from .NET 9.x so I assume that this will stop working next year.

How can I fix this? The error is in code generated by the WinForms designer, so I can't see how to do so...

To reproduce this issue:

1. Create a directory named "WinForms1" and from the Visual Studio 2022 command line change to that directory.
2. Run the following command: `dotnew new winforms`
3. Open the created "WinForms1.csproj" file with Visual Studio 2022.
4. Edit `Form1` in the WinForms designer.
5. Add a `ListView` to the form.
6. Right-click the `ListView` and select *Edit Groups...*
7. Click *Add* and then click *OK*.
8. In the form's properties set `Localizable` to true.
9. Build the project.

Now you get the following warning:

```
Form1.resx : warning MSB3825: 
Resource "listView1.Groups" of type "System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" is deserialized via BinaryFormatter at runtime. 
BinaryFormatter is deprecated due to possible security risks and will be removed with .NET 9.
If you wish to continue using it, set property "GenerateResourceWarnOnBinaryFormatterUse" to false.
```

Comment: This is a problem for Microsoft to solve, reimplementing ListView without knowing which approach they'll take is not practical..  Meanwhile, it tells you what you need to do about it while they are figuring this out.

Comment: It's just a warning, related to the mentioned [GenerateResourceWarnOnBinaryFormatterUse](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets) Property, set by default to true when targeting .NET 8+. Since you have acknowledged the potential issue, you can suppress the warning, adding `<GenerateResourceWarnOnBinaryFormatterUse>false</GenerateResourceWarnOnBinaryFormatterUse>` in, e.g., the main `<PropertyGroup>` of the Project's configuration file. What's going to be in .NET 9, about this and other stuff, is still undetermined

Comment: @Jimi I've already disabled the warning; what I was worried about is what will happen when .NET 9 comes out - will localised a localised `ListView` containing a `Group` be broken? I would hope it will be fixed by then, however. I'll check out the .NET 9 preview once it comes out some time next year.

Comment: I don't know and I don't know anyone that knows (or anyone that knows whether there's anything to know, at this time). As you have probably noticed, the WinForms Designer is still in Preview (and still a lot of stuff is missing, though something has changed in the data binding department, e.g., the WPF-MVVM *inspired* [CommandBinding](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/winforms-cross-platform-dotnet-maui-command-binding/)) -- In one year, many things can happen. You cannot do much yourself by now. You've being told that something could create an issue, in the future

Comment: Looking at [the discussion here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/8827) it seems like the generated code uses something that references `BinaryFormatter` but doesn't actually use it, so it should be OK.

Comment: It's more related to the overall effort of the [BinaryFormatter Obsoletion Strategy](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md), which implies that [All first-party dotnet org code bases complete migration away from BinaryFormatter (.NET 8)](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md#all-first-party-dotnet-org-code-bases-complete-migration-away-from-binaryformatter-net-8) (in the life-time of .NET 8, but started in .NET 5)...

Comment: ...which inevitably leads to [BinaryFormatter infrastructure removed from .NET (.NET 9)](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md#binaryformatter-infrastructure-removed-from-net-net-9) (read the final note). You may be interested party if you force binary serialization (requires a switch) using a deprecated API. What the WinForms Designer will do is still undefined