# How to fix warning MSB3825 due to deprecated BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core, binaryformatter

I have an existing WinForms application. After updating to .NET 8, I now get warnings.

> Warning MSB3825 Resource "imageList1.ImageStream" of type "System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" is deserialized via BinaryFormatter at runtime. BinaryFormatter is deprecated due to possible security risks and will be removed with .NET 9. If you wish to continue using it, set property "GenerateResourceWarnOnBinaryFormatterUse" to false.

Apparently `BinaryFormatter` has been deprecated. Okay, fine. I don't even know what it does. But I don't know how to resolve these warnings.

More information is available at https://aka.ms/msbuild/net8-binaryformatter. The recommended action is to *"migrate away from BinaryFormatter due to its security and reliability flaws."*

But how to do this? I never opted into using this component. The error text appears to indicate it's being used by `ImageList`. When I search for my program, the only places this symbol shows up is in comments in my resx files! It is WinForms that is referencing this type. So how do I prevent WinForms from referencing it?

Comment: Your issue is probably this one here: [NET8: BinaryFormatter not supported when .resx contains "application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64" #9701](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/9701).

Comment: @dbc: Yes, it appears to be. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a resolution. Sad, WinForms has become completely unusable. I had numerous errors when upgrading to .NET 8. The form designer takes an eternity to come up. And now I see my Toolbox has zero controls in it!

Comment: Reading through that issue and [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/6267), looks like MSFT's plan is to require WInForms developers to enable `BinayrFormatter` in .NET 8, and in .NET 9 the WinForms team will somehow make the problem go away.

Comment: @dbc: Where did you get that about requiring WinForm developers to enable `BinaryFormatter`? I saw there is a setting for those who want to use it anyway. But didn't see a requirement to use it.

Comment: You can disable that warning. Open the project file (double click) and add `<GenerateResourceWarnOnBinaryFormatterUse>false</GenerateResourceWarnOnBinaryFormatterUse>` to the `<PropertyGroup>` block. Probably your `ImageList` components and the Resources file are empty. You also need to fix that manually if so.

Comment: In this particular case you can solve the problem by adding the images to the `ImageList` at run-time, eg. in the constructor. The images themselves still can be resources. Individual bitmap resources are not added by `BinaryFormatter` so it must work.

Comment: @JonathanWood - it was [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/9701#issuecomment-1672100871) by [JeremyKuhne](https://github.com/JeremyKuhne) of MSFT: *We're planning to figure out a solution for the WinForms designer for .NET 9 for core WinForms types (which this is one)... **WinForms and WPF projects should have the `BinaryFormatter` enabled by default for .NET 8.** If this isn't happening for your project we can investigate...*

Comment: [How to fix warning MSB3825 for a localizable WinForm containing a ListView with a Group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77565011/7444103) -- @dbc BinaryFormatter is used by default, in different scenarios, not just this one. That's probably what JK is referring to, by saying *[...] should have the BinaryFormatter enabled by default* -- This warning is a quite useful reminder that the entire infrastructure behind BinaryFormatter will be removed in .NET 9. So, if you rely on it for some reason...

Comment: @dr.null: I saw that. But I'm trying to solve the issue, not just suppress the warnings.

Comment: nah, that's a MSFT issue to solve.